# Different result from JavaScript RegExp in "rhino1.7.6" vs "V8"

Tags: javascript, regex, v8, rhino

currently, I found the same JavaScript RegExp might generate different result in different JavaScript Engines, here is an example:
In Chrome V8 JS engine,

```
/\x3c/.test("\x3c")  --> returns true

/\x3c/.test(function() {  return "\x3c"  }) -->returns ***false***
```

In rhino1.7.6,I typed the command like this:

```
>java -jar js.jar

  Rhino 1.7.6 2015 04 15

js> /\x3c/.test(function() {  return "\x3c"  })

  true

js>
```

And I tested these two:

```
/\x3c/.test("\x3c")  --> returns true

/\x3c/.test(function() {  return "\x3c"  }) -->returns ***true***
```

I am wondering why these two engines generate different result. I believe they must be compliant with some standards.

Please correct me if I am wrong. And moreover, if it is a special occasion, would you please kindly tell me if there are some configurations I can tell JS engine on these special occasions.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're passing a function reference into `.test()`, not the result of *calling* the function. The function you pass will be converted to a string.  That said, I think Chrome's behavior is incorrect.

Comment: Can you show your testing code for Rhino?

Comment: @nhahtdh, at first, I found the behaviour of a webpage is wired. Then, I downloaded the webpage and tested it. Then, I found it is caused by this :  /\x3c/.test(function() {  return "\x3c"  }) .   To make it easier for you guys, I downloaded "rhino1.7.6", and tested it like this: \n>java -jar js.jar
Rhino 1.7.6 2015 04 15
js> /\x3c/.test(function() {  return "\x3c"  })
true
----------------------------  As you can see ,the result is true. However, in Chrome, it is false.

Comment: @nhahtdh, at first, I found the behaviour of a webpage is wired. Then, I downloaded the webpage and tested it. Then, I found it is caused by this :  /\x3c/.test(function() {  return "\x3c"  }) .   To make it easier for you guys, I downloaded "rhino1.7.6" and you can see my test input in the question since I can not type newline in this comment :)

Answer (score 3):

Given the value `function() { return "\x3c" }`

- **Chrome** converts it to the string `"function() { return "\x3c" }"`, that is, a literal backslash followed by "x3c".
- **Rhino** converts it to the string `"function () { return "<"; }"`, that is, it reformats the function definition.

Both are actually correct behaviour. The ECMA-262 (a.k.a. Javascript) standard [says that](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.tostring) `String(func)` should return "an implementation-dependent String source code representation of *func*."