# Parsing website html code: htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

In this code i am trying to parse the html code of the website given by url.

I initially tried with `jsoup.connect.get` but the html code that was getting loaded in the document was not what I was seeing in my browser. Then I started using htmlunit based on feedback given in net that jsoup would not be able to retrieve html code of javascript/ajax based pages completely. When I use htmlunit package and its `WebClient` class, I am getting following errors:

> Nov 05, 2017 12:40:15 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
>   SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Exceeded maximum stack depth] sourceName=[script in http://www.dspblackrock.com/about-us/mandatory-disclosure/month-end-portfolio-disclosures from (8, 9) to (26, 10)] line=[22] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
>   Nov 05, 2017 12:40:15 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   Nov 05, 2017 12:40:15 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
>   SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Exceeded maximum stack depth] sourceName=[http://www.dspblackrock.com/TSPD/08ca5204faab20006bf1735bede287affd051075f25a20bf70034ef55ad0ac427b287aacb10e6976?type=7] line=[70] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]

Am new to java. Firstly is the use of htmlUnit the right approach for the problem at hand? If so how to resolve above errors?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class URLToFile {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
      String url;

      UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();
      try {

         url = "http://www.dspblackrock.com/about-us/mandatory-disclosure/month-end-portfolio-disclosures";
         WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52);
         webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
         webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
         HtmlPage myPage = webClient.getPage(url);
         webClient.close();
         Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myPage.asXml());
         System.out.println(doc);
      }  catch (MalformedURLException mue) {

             System.out.println("Ouch - a MalformedURLException happened.");
             mue.printStackTrace();
             System.exit(1);

          } catch (IOException ioe) {

             System.out.println("Oops- an IOException happened.");
             ioe.printStackTrace();
             System.exit(1);

          } finally {
              System.out.println("Entered finally");
          } // end of 'finally' clause
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using the latest SNAPSHOT build of HtmlUnit. Have done a short test with this version and the page works.

Doing

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myPage.asXml());
```

is a bad idea from my point of view.

1. HtmlUnit has is own model. You can do all the things you are able to do with Jsoup with the HtmlUnit API also.
2. You might loose some information based on the conversions you did (HtmlUnit DOM -> XML -> Jsoup DOM)
3. If you use the HtmlUnit API (and model) you still have javascript support (e.g. if you click a button all the events will be triggered).

After some more analysis i found this in the page (minimized/obfuscated) source code:

```
iL(/\x3c/.test(function() {
    return "\x3c"
}) & !/x3d/.test(function() {
    return "'x3'+'d';"
}));
```

Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714382/different-result-from-javascript-regexp-in-rhino1-7-6-vs-v8)

Looks like the folks behind the page are trying to detect rhino. I fear it will be a hard job to make this page available using HtmlUnit.

Comment: What is the latest snapshot version of HtmlUnit? I am using htmlunit-2.27-OSGi.jar. This is the latest I could get.

Comment: That is the latest release. Do you need the OSGi version? Try using 2.28-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Have no idea what OSGI version would do different. Can you please point me to the 2.28 version jar file. I tried googling for it but unsuccesful.

Comment: There seems to be another problem. With the latest snapshot the page does not detect the js support of HtmlUnit. Based on this i got a different result than in real browsers. Please open an HtmlUnit issue.

Comment: Then is there any other way to get the html code for the page?